# understanding of google-cloud-endpoints?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

cloud-endpoints.
I am following Udacity tutorial.i a bit confused with the flow of request and response,the below is my understanding 
A endpoint should be annotated with `@Api` and endpoint method is annotated with `@ApiMethod` and these methods should not return primitive data types.the below is one endpoint method

```
@ApiMethod(name = "saveProfile", path = "profile", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)

public Profile saveProfile(ProfileForm profileForm) throws UnauthorizedException {

    String userId = null;
    String mainEmail = null;
    String displayName = "Your name will go here";
    TeeShirtSize teeShirtSize = TeeShirtSize.NOT_SPECIFIED;

    if(profileForm.getTeeShirtSize() != null)
        teeShirtSize = profileForm.getTeeShirtSize();

    displayName = profileForm.getDisplayName();

    Profile profile = new Profile(userId, displayName, mainEmail, teeShirtSize);

    return profile;
}
```

The below is my ProfileForm and Profile classes

```
public class ProfileForm {
private String displayName;

private TeeShirtSize teeShirtSize;

private ProfileForm () {}

    public ProfileForm(String displayName, TeeShirtSize teeShirtSize) {
    this.displayName = displayName;
    this.teeShirtSize = teeShirtSize;
}

public String getDisplayName() {
    return displayName;
}

public TeeShirtSize getTeeShirtSize() {
    return teeShirtSize;
}

public static enum TeeShirtSize {
    NOT_SPECIFIED,
    XS,
    S,
    M,
    L, 
    XL, 
    XXL,
    XXXL
  }
}
```

```
public class Profile {
String displayName;
String mainEmail;
TeeShirtSize teeShirtSize;


String userId;

    public Profile (String userId, String displayName, String mainEmail, TeeShirtSize teeShirtSize) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.displayName = displayName;
    this.mainEmail = mainEmail;
    this.teeShirtSize = teeShirtSize;
}

public String getDisplayName() {
    return displayName;
}

public String getMainEmail() {
    return mainEmail;
}

public TeeShirtSize getTeeShirtSize() {
    return teeShirtSize;
}

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

    private Profile() {}

}
```

Here `ProfileForm` is request parameter and `Profile` is response.i deployed in locahost and by using the below url i have tested 
http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/explorer
in request body i added two parameters as displayName,teeShirtSize So can any one please explain why i am getting response as 404 ? the below is the screen shot

[image]
And as of my understanding i don't need to load appengine client.js because i am not testing in webpage. i am testing in api-explorer.Please explain how response is generated when you invoke  google-cloud-endpoint?
Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code for ProfileForm?

Comment: @Eliot thanks for your reply and now i have added the ProfileForm and Profile classes.

Comment: are you getting any logs in your GAE server showing you actually hit the Endpoint?

Comment: No i am not getting any logs.

Answer (score 0):

I used 1.9.3 version of google-app-engine , then i changed to 1.9.20 now it's working fine. Still i am hiving questions like why it's not worked in 1.9.3 ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's likely (but not certain, because I don't see your `@Api` annotation) that it wasn't working because you set the root parameter in your annotation. There were recent changes which made the API explorer always honor the root, which broke the local development experience. A recent SDK version changed this to make it work again. If you notice, your explorer screenshot says:

> POST **https://your-app-id.appspot.com/**_ah/api/conference/v1/profile

Where it should say:

> POST **http://localhost:8080/**_ah/api/conference/v1/profile